# Unable to get a single record as an array from Firebase, but complete list works

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

[This Answer did not help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29309537/how-can-i-get-a-single-record-from-angularfire-collection-synchronized-from-fire) which is for something quite similar.  I am using angular 1.3.15, with Firebase 2.2.4 and AngularFire 1.1.1.

I have a factory to return a reference to the proper Firebase (https://.firebaseio.com

```
angular.module('MyModule')
    .constant('FIREBASE_URL', 'https://xxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/');

angular.module('MyModule')
    .factory('GetFireBaseObject', function(FIREBASE_URL) {
        return {
            BaseURL: function() {
                return new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
            },
            DataURL: function(Node) {
                return new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + Node);
            }
        };
    }
);
```

Then the controller is trying to get data from the factory.

```
angular.module('MyModule').factory("StoresData", ["$firebaseArray", "GetFireBaseObject", 
    function($firebaseArray, GetFireBaseObject) {
        var StoresData = GetFireBaseObject.DataURL('Stores/');

        return {
            AllStores: function() {
                return $firebaseArray(StoresData);
            },
            OneStore: function(StoreKey) {
                var StoreKeyNo = parseInt(StoreKey);
                return $firebaseArray(StoresData.child(StoreKeyNo));
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

The AllStores reference call will return everything.  However, I do not get a record using the OneStore call.  I have validated that my keys are numeric in the Firebase structure (no quotes), but still this does not find the record.

```
angular.module('MyModule').controller('StoreCtrl', ['$scope', "StoresData",
    function ($scope, StoresData) {

        $scope.Stores = StoresData.AllStores();
        $scope.store = {};

        $scope.DeleteStore = function(StoreId) {
            $scope.Stores.$remove(StoreId);
        };

        $scope.SaveStore = function(store) {
            store.$id = store.Key;   // Integer Value
            $scope.Stores.push(store);
            $scope.Stores.$save(store);

            $scope.store.Key = "";
            $scope.store.Description = "";
        };

        $scope.SelectStore = function(StoreId) {
            var OneStore = StoresData.OneStore(StoreId);
            $scope.store.Key = OneStore.Key;
            $scope.store.Description = OneStore.Description;
        };

    }
]);
```

I am not seeing anything returned in the debugger or on screen. I am not even worried about the update right now, just trying to get a select to work.  I have validated that the HTML is returning the proper Key for the record I am trying to access.

Changing OneStore to:

```
            OneStore: function(StoreKey) {
                var StoresData = GetFireBaseObject.DataURL('Stores/' + StoreKey);
                return new $firebaseArray(StoresData);
```

does not work either. The data returned is an empty array.

Comment: What if you try to put in the link to the child directly in the Onestore function? `$firebaseArray('https://xxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/child')`

Comment: You can directly query on the child if you want, that is what I meant. Edited my previous comment

Comment: Did not seem to fix it.  I even tried hard coding the path without luck. Must be something silly?

Comment: Oh btw, I see you are using a normal push method to add to the array. This is actually not a good practice. To keep your array synchronized with your Firebase data you should use $add. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-addnewdata I see you tried it, must be something silly indeed.

Comment: @Mikey I used the Push method to set the ID (Key value) as I want proper keys, not random one from Firebase.  The data is staying syncronized though with any other change, provided I use the proper keys. The issue is in trying to work with one record.  If I make changes on Firebase, I do see them right away on the webpage.

Comment: Ok. Yeah there is also a different way to add your own keys in a more angular style, but you say your array remains synced so that is not an issue. Very strange indeed. Is your request successful? Can you use the $loaded() promise to check if it returns succesfully?

Comment: We have [a guide explaining every question posited here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html):  use $firebaseObject for records, not $firebaseArray; $loaded is covered on page 1 in the intro; use $add and not push(). Save yourself some pain and read the guide.

Comment: @Kato Thanks. I was working with the guide and some other samples.  I am using Firebase temporarily in place of a REST server, so I am expecting numeric keys from our servers.  As such, I was using post & save to set the $id to a key that I am simply entering during testing.

Comment: @Kato But if you load it as an object, you can't push new stuff anymore because the $add method is not available for $firebaseObject

Comment: There are several ways to push child values to an object. The simplest is `obj[ childName ] = value` followed by $save(). Also, `obj.$getRef().child( childName ).set( value );` when dealing with large data sets and complex setups. In fact, you don't need a synchronized object or array for the purposes of writing data, just binding data to local Angular-specific models .

Comment: @Kato Ok, so when you want a collection returned it is advised to use an array otherwise an object? But still, if you use an array on a single record it should still return an array with one object in it?

Comment: @Kato If you would like to move your comments to an answer I can accept it as fixing my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to push child values to an object. The simplest is `obj[ childName ] = value` followed by `$save()`.

Also, `obj.$getRef().child( childName ).set( value );` will be great when dealing with large data sets and complex setups. In fact, you don't need a synchronized object or array for the purposes of writing data, as these are really just for binding data to local Angular-specific models.

You should generally use `$firebaseArray` for collections and `$firebaseObject` for key/value pairs that represent a single record, as recommended in the guide. They both have specific tools available for dealing with those unique types. Also keep in mind that data that should be saved back to the server is added using `$add()`, not the Array prototype method `push()`.

If you attempt to take an object node like {foo: 'bar', baz: 'boo'} and turn that into a `$firebaseArray`, then it's still treated as a collection. All the array does internally is call `child_added` on the path you specify. So in this case, `foo` and `baz` would both be treated as "records" and added to the array as objects with `$value` attributes equal to their string values. Much of the technicals like this are covered in [the guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html).