# Getting the reference from $firebaseArray to make a new reference object

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29309537/213156), I need to be able to get an element from a collection as a Firebase reference, ie given a `$firebaseArray` I need a `$firebaseObject` pointing to one of its elements. Unlike that example, I can't just hard-code a path the array and take a child from there because the location of the array will vary. And I can't use `$firebaseArray.$getRecord()` or the object provided by my `ng-repeat` followed by `array.$save()` because I may need to do a `push()` on this element.

So I settled on this reusable approach:

In a service:

```
function selectElement(array, element) {
  var obj = $firebaseObject(array.$ref().child(element.$id));
  return obj;
}
```

In the controller:

```
function onItemClicked(e) {
  vm.selected = dataservice.selectElement(vm.observations, e);
}
```

In the template:

```
<div class="list-item" ng-repeat="o in vm.observations" ng-click="vm.onItemClicked(o)">
```

The first line of `selectElement` produces an error: `array.$ref(...).child is not a function at Object.selectElement`

Here `array` has all the properties you'd expect, but logging `array.$ref()` shows this obfuscated object:

```
Y {k: Ji, path: P, n: Ce, pc: true}
```

That is what it looks like from the time the array is created. What's going on here and how do I use this reference? Is there another way to get a working Firebase object out of an array?

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit more: "And I can't use $firebaseArray.$getRecord() or the object provided by my ng-repeat followed by array.$save() because I may need to do a push() on this element."

Comment: Both of those mechanisms return the raw data object at that location. I need to get a reference to it so that I can push children to it. More specifically, records at various place in the database, which I'm fetching as arrays, may have lists of comments as children.